# Circular control in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-controls, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I am trying to make a circular control like the one you see on the attached image. It looks like a circular `seekbar` but it is not a circular `seekbar` as the thumb can move infinitely around the circular rim.

[image]

I have tried to modify a number of libraries of circular `seekbars`, but none worked properly (precisely because it is not a `seekbar`). 
The closest I have found is the HGDial library of Warwick Wright [Link](https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hgdialrepo/src/master/), but I can't find a way to put a layout within the circle with his library and I need to put some customized `seekbars` inside the circle and have them working.

Any ideas? Help much appreciated.